# Is there a quick way to snap a mesh to the cursor, at the selected elements of the mesh?

Tags: mesh, add-on, snapping

I find myself often needing to align meshes to a certain point that isn't one of the mesh's origin.  It would be convenient if I could use the selected elements of a mesh as if it were the origin of the mesh for snaps of the object.  (Several commands use the selected elements in object mode, so I don't this is a weird thing to do.)

Right now I can temporarily move the object's origin to where I want the snap's target to be and then snap the object before setting the origin back, but that's several commands for an action I find myself wanting often. Is there a command I'm missing, or an add-on that adds this?

I'm asking this question before I write a script to do this so that I don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: sounds like a 3 liner script - shouldn't be too hard to write....i think you needed more time to write this question ;)

Comment: Oh, definitely.  But I'd feel stupid if I ever found the "right" way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of snapping certain vertices of a Mesh to some arbitrary location.  You should first position the (independent) "3d cursor" to where you want to move the vertices (View Sidebar, or Object :: Snap Cursor to Selected):

[image]

, then select the Object, select your vertices in Edit mode, and RMB, Snap Vertices :: Selection to Cursor:

[image]

Comment: I don't want to edit the object, I'm just moving it.  Your other answer is closer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where I use the Add-on "Align Tools", which you can enable in Preferences :: Add-Ons.

First I moved the cursor to my desired destination, perhaps by just entering the coordinates in the View :: 3D Cursor side panel.

[image]

Then I created an empty that I might eventually delete.   Then I selected my objects to move (here a sphere and a cube), lastly selecting the destination Empty object, and aligned Y and Z location as shown.

[image]

Comment: This might be it, but I need to play around with it to be sure.